# Accessing Outlook REST API from C# Console App on Windows XP

Tags: c#, rest, outlook, ms-office, exchangewebservices

I'm updating a very old VB.NET console application to C#. The old application used the Domino libraries to send and search through received email through a Lotus Notes client.

My organization has since migrated all email to Office 365 and the Lotus Notes server will be retired soon. I need to be able to send emails through the Outlook REST API, and use the API to search for any email received since the last time the app ran with a specific key word in the subject (no need to actually read the email, just the subject.)

I've set up the app in https://dev.outlook.com/AppRegistration, checked all the Mail API boxes and copied the Client ID. But now I'm unsure how to proceed, since every tutorial I see involves an interactive session where the user grants access to the application. My application needs to be able to run unattended. No live interaction will be possible.

To further complicate the issue, I'm developing this app using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express on a Windows XP virtual machine. I could probably get our IS department to upgrade the virtual machine, but most likely Windows 7/Visual Studio 2013 will be as up-to-date as I can get.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial for authenticating with the Outlook REST API in a C# .NET console application without requiring user interaction?

Comment: see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/

Comment: This app is not running on a web server.

Comment: Its doesn't mater what your trying to do is refereed to as headless or implicit auth flow http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

Comment: I guess what's confusing me is that every example I see of this has two components -- a web API and a client app. My solution doesn't include a component that runs on a web server, only a client app.